# iOS - drawRect: called twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, drawrect

I am really new to iOS and I've read similar questions but none of the answers worked.
I have a tableview with custom cells presenting graphs (custom `UIView`) and past football matches. Not in the same cell, but it goes like graph-cell (`BCCGraphCell`) -> corresponding matches (`BCCPastMatchCell`), graph-cell -> corresponding matches..

I'm using Storyboards and in my custom cell I've added a graph subview (`BCCGraphView`). Outlets are ok. I override `drawRect:` method to draw the graph but it's only called twice. What am I missing here?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifierPastMatchCell = @"pastMatchCell";
    static NSString *cellIdentifierGraphCell = @"graphCell";
    if (indexPath.section % 2 == 0) {
        BCCGraphCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierGraphCell];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[BCCGraphCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifierGraphCell];
        }
        return cell;
    }
    BCCPastMatchCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierPastMatchCell];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[BCCPastMatchCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifierPastMatchCell];
    }
    BCCMatch *matchForCell = [self.pastMatches objectForKey:self.pastMatchesKeyNames[indexPath.section]][indexPath.row];

    [self configurePastMatchCell:cell];
    return cell;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    self.numberOfMatches = 6; // It's suppose to affect the 6 past match cells
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // **** Grid thikckness and color ****
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, [BCCUIConstant kGraphGridThickness]);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[BCCUIConstant colorForViewGraphGrid] CGColor]);

    // Draw the Xlines
    for (int i = 0; i <= [self numberOfGridLinesX]; i++) {
        [self setNeedsDisplay];

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, [self offsetX] + i * [self stepX], kGraphTop);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, [self offsetX] + i * [self stepX], kGraphBottom);
    }
    // Draw the Ylines
    for (int i = 0; i < [self numberOfGridLinesY]; i++) {
        [self setNeedsDisplay];

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, kGraphBottom - [self offsetY] - i * [self stepY]);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, kGraphWidth, kGraphBottom - [self offsetY] - i * [self stepY]);
    }

    // Commit drawing
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Comment: Either use Outlets or Init, if you use both it will call it 2 times,because Outlet invokes initWithDecoder method. both will call drawRect respectively.

Answer (score -1):

remove setNeedsDisplay in drawRect

```
[tableView reloadData];
[self setNeedsDisplay];
```